# Portable server with support for SSI

Tags: ssi, portable-applications

I need a portable small server that supports SSI (server Side Includes).  Does anybody know of any portable (i.e. doesn't need installing to work, this way I can put in on my flash drive) servers that can do this?

Comment: for what OS do you plan to use it?

Comment: I will be doing this on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lighty2Go](http://www.lighty2go.com/) is a portable distibution of [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/), a very popular lightweight http server.  It [supports ssi](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs%3aConfigurationOptions#mod_ssi-server-side-includes).  This distro includes php and mysql in portable versions, they're probably easy to remove if you don't need them.